# How to apply multiple field options to one field in Django

Tags: django

I'm using Django, is there a way to apply foreign key and ChartField to one field at the same time? Sometimes I want to allow the user to enter a value that is not in the foreign key. I've googled for a long time and found various ways, but I can't find a solution. Please help.

[models.py]

```
class Supporting(models.Model):
    assignment = models.ForeignKey(Assignment, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Foreign key only allows ids or objects of models that it has relation with. it can never ever accept text. if you want to this field to be a foreign key for other models too then there is a solution. you can use generic foreign key

Answer (score 0):

You Might be looking for a through Model between Supporting and Assignment.
As per your question, you might require multiple fields defining the nature of relation between two models and Through Models are exactly made for that!

[Django Through Models Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through_fields)

Answer (score 0):

You can't add ForeignKey and text in Django to a single field. You have to create a foreign key (Assignment) object, and then, after a page refresh, you can attach it to the current model.

I the page refresh is not needed, AJAX has to be used.